# Why doesn't my OpenSCAD model render correctly in thingiverse?

Tags: render, openscad

I created a parametric OpenSCAD model, and tried importing it into thingiverse customizer. However, it is supposed to look like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXFsQ.jpg, but it looks closer to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOF5b.png

Does thingiverse simply not render anything correctly, or is there a problem with the model (code reproduced below)

```
//Do Nothing = 0
//Increment = 1
//Decrement = 2
//Increment + Zerocheck = 3
//Decrement + Zerocheck = 4

//Text position:
//Top left: 0
//Left side inwards: 1
//Left side outwards: 2

/* [Instructions] */

//Instructions for the Left Counter
Left_counter = 0; // [0:Do Nothing,1:Increment,2:Decrement,3:Increment and Check Zero,4:Decrement and Check Zero]

//Instructions for the Middle Counter
Middle_counter = 0; // [0:Do Nothing,1:Increment,2:Decrement,3:Increment and Check Zero,4:Decrement and Check Zero]

//Instructions for the Right Counter
Right_counter = 0; // [0:Do Nothing,1:Increment,2:Decrement,3:Increment and Check Zero,4:Decrement and Check Zero]

//Hole that currently has no purpose
No_Purpose_Hole = 0; // [0:Don't create hole,1:Create hole]

/* [Text] */

//Text to show
Text="";

//Can be used for card number, description, etc.
Text_position=0;// [0:Top left corner (1-3 chars),1:Left side facing inwards (1-12 chars),2:Left side facing outwards (1-12 chars)]

/* [Hidden] */

$fn=30;

include <write/Write.scad>;

punchcard();

module punchcard(){

scale([25.4,25.4,25.4])
difference(){
card(Text);
union(){


if (Left_counter == 1)
    hole(3);
if (Left_counter == 2)
    hole(1);
if (Left_counter == 3){
    hole(3);
    hole(5);}
if (Left_counter == 4){
    hole(1);
    hole(5);}

if (Middle_counter == 1)
    hole(2);
if (Middle_counter == 2)
    hole(8);
if (Middle_counter == 3){
    hole(2);
    hole(4);}
if (Middle_counter == 4){
    hole(8);
    hole(4);}

if (Right_counter == 1)
    hole(10);
if (Right_counter == 2)
    hole(7);
if (Right_counter == 3){
    hole(10);
    hole(9);}
if (Right_counter == 4){
    hole(7);
    hole(9);}

if (No_Purpose_Hole == 1)
    hole(6);


}}}


module card(text){
    difference(){
        cube([3.3,1.8,.1]);
        translate([0,0,-.5])union(){
        //positioning holes
            translate([1.65,.25,0])
                cylinder(d=.25,h=1);
            translate([1.65, 1.55,0])
                cylinder(d=.25,h=1);
        //threading holes
            for(x=[.125,3.175])
                for(y=[.125,1.675])
                    translate([x,y,0])
                        cylinder(d=.125,h=1);
        }
if (Text_position == 0)
    translate([.4,1.675,.1])            
    scale([.04,.04,.1])
        writecube(text = Text, face = "top", size = .01);
if (Text_position == 1)
    translate([.1,.9,.1])
    scale([.04,.04,.1])
    rotate([0,0,90])
        writecube(text = Text, face = "top", size = .01);
if (Text_position == 2)
    translate([.1,.9,.1])
    scale([.04,.04,.1])
    rotate([0,0,-90])
        writecube(text = Text, face = "top", size = .01);


    }
}

module hole (position){

    translate([.3*position,0.7,-.5])
    union(){
        cylinder(d=.2, h=1);
        translate([-.1,0,0])
            cube([.2,.3,1]);
        translate([0,.3,0])
            cylinder(d=.2, h=1);
        }}
```

Comment: According to comment below, this can no longer be reproduced since a Thingiverse update.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify how the rendering of thing-verse is off? The second image simply looks like the rendering of OpenSCAD. If you have already found an answer to your question, please let me know about the answer.

Comment: It works now- I think that the thingiverse update to 2015.03 fixed it, as it works without changing the file at all. (And looking at it, I accidentally swapped the two images above)